# Redirect same port of two Docker containers on different ports

Tags: docker

I need to run a Java app into several Docker containers in order to isolate their execution.

This app listens on port 12345 and I run my docker container with "-p 12345:5000" to redirect the port 12345 (from Docker container) to the port 5000 of my host. It works fine.

But when I run another Docker container with "-p 12345:50001", I have an error "Bind for 0.0.0.0:12345 failed: port is already allocated."

I don't understand why .. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mixed up your host and container ports!

The host port comes first and must be unique. The container port comes second. You probably want something like this, if your java apps both run on the same port in the container:

```
"-p 12345:50000"
"-p 12346:50000"
```

Or this if they really expose different ports in the container:

```
"-p 12345:50000"
"-p 12346:50001"
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to use the same port?